# python pandas - joining specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a main dataframe (MbrKPI4), and I want to left join it with another dataframe (mbrsdf). They have the same index. I am successful with the below.

```
MbrKPI4.join(mbrsdf['Gender'])
```

However, I want to join more columns from mbrsdf, and the below does not work (MemoryError). Is there a way to join that I can select the columns I want from mbrsdf?

```
MbrKPI4.join(mbrsdf['Gender'], mbrsdf['Marital Status'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on documentation for [join()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) I think you want to pass in an array of dataframes to left join by, or chain join calls.

```
d1.join([d2['Gender'], d2['Marital Status']])
d1.join(d2['Gender']).join(d2['Marital Status'])
```

Hope that works.